# for loop value or reference

Tags: java, foreach

I'm having some trouble understanding the third loop in my code below. After the second loop the list didn't change so I assumed that d was a copy of the element in the list. After the third output the element has its name changed so it's not a copy.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Dog> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(new Dog("a"));
        list.add(new Dog("b"));
        list.add(new Dog("c"));
        list.forEach(d -> System.out.println("dog name: " + d.getName())); // a,b,c

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            list.set(i, new Dog("z"));
        }
        list.forEach(d -> System.out.println("dog name: " + d.getName())); // z,z,z
        for (Dog d : list) {
            d = new Dog("y");
        }
        list.forEach(d -> System.out.println("dog name: " + d.getName())); // z,z,z

        for (Dog d : list) {
            d.setName("w");
        }
        list.forEach(d -> System.out.println("dog name: " + d.getName())); // w,w,w

    }

    public static class Dog {
        private String name;

        public Dog(String n) {
            name = n;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you consider the `forEach` to be a loop or no?

Comment: @erip yes But I meant the for loops, not the foreach's.

Comment: Understood. I submitted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    list.add(new Dog("a"));
    list.add(new Dog("b"));
    list.add(new Dog("c"));
```

This adds three `Dog`s to your list with names `a`, `b`, and `c`. They are then printed:

```
    list.forEach(d -> System.out.println("dog name: " + d.getName()));
```

> a,b,c

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        list.set(i, new Dog("z"));
    }
```

They are then being **overwritten** within the list (i.e., replaced) at index i (for all i in the range of the size of the list) by dogs with name `z`. They are all then printed:

```
    list.forEach(d -> System.out.println("dog name: " + d.getName()));
```

> z,z,z

You then created a new temporary reference to a dog for each dog in your list and name them all `y`. After the loop, this temporary reference goes out of scope, hence the dogs still being named `z`.

```
    for (Dog d : list) {
        d = new Dog("y");
    }
    list.forEach(d -> System.out.println("dog name: " + d.getName()));
```

> z,z,z

You then rename every dog in your list to `w`.

```
    for (Dog d : list) {
        d.setName("w");
    }

    list.forEach(d -> System.out.println("dog name: " + d.getName()));
```

> w,w,w

Answer (score 1):

in your second for-loop, you are referencing the variable d to another Dog instance.

in your third for-loop, you are changing the instance.